# The Android navigation bar automatically changes colors according to criteria

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I have a way to decide whether or not to change the color of the navigation bar based on whether a view is on the screen. The method has been written, but I do not know how to call it. I call this method with a button click event, but it is very hard. Want him to call automatically, rather than click on the event call, how can i do?

```
public class Index extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.index);
}

private void changeNavigationColour(View view){
        Point p = new Point();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(p);
        int[] loacation = new int[2];
        view.getLocationInWindow(loacation);
        Toast.makeText(this, Arrays.toString(loacation),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Rect ivRect = new Rect(view.getLeft(),view.getTop(),view.getRight(),view.getBottom());
        LinearLayout head = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.index_head);
        if(view.getLocalVisibleRect(ivRect)){
             //Change the navigation color
            head.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));
        }else {
             //Change the navigation color
            head.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        }
}
```

Comment: post what you've tried so far to help understand the issue

Comment: show us your code.

Comment: you need to be more clear about this 'criteria' change.. what is it? how do you get it?

Comment: As above code, "changeNavigationColour (View view)" how to make this method automatically call. Like "Button" has been waiting for the user to click, and this method is to wait for the view after leaving the screen call

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment it seems you need to call `changeNavigationColour(View view)` based on a phone call status

For that you can use a `PhoneStateListener`

```
public class Index extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.index);

        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
        telephonyManager.listen(new myPhoneStateChangeListener(),PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);   
    }

    public class myPhoneStateChangeListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
            // call changeNavigationColour based on the state

        }
    }
}
```

You also need to have this in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```